# no such file directory issue with xml post from curl

Tags: rest, web-services, unix, curl, libcurl

when i run this command from bash i get the below error

```
$curl -X POST -HContent-type:application/xml --data "<root><myXmlTagsGoHere</root>" "<http://MyUrlGoesHere>" -o/home/myusername/myResponse.txt
```

> `curl: (1) Protocol <http not supported or disabled in libcurl`

but when i remove quotes for my url using below command

```
$curl -X POST -HContent-type:application/xml --data "<root><myXmlTagsGoHere</root>" <http://MyUrlGoesHere> -o/home/myusername/myResponse.txt
```

i get `No such file or directory` error...

What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter should be `http://MyUrlGoesHere` not `<http://MyUrlGoesHere>` -- and of course if there's special characters like `&` in the url, it should be `"http://MyUrlGoesHere"`

When you have it as `<http://MyUrlGoesHere>` without quotes, it's a stdout/in redirection.